# Disable loader for some ajax queries (JqueryMobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use the loader of jquery mobile for all my ajax queries, but in only one case, i would like the loader to be hidden.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: add a parameter to your ajax call and check if true then only call code to display loading in the before send...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getData (urlPath, showLoading) {
    $.ajax({
        url : urlPath,
        dataType: 'script',
        beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){
            if(showLoading) 
            {
               //call loading code
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //success logic here
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            // error handling here
        },
        complete: function(){
            console.log('DONE');
            if (showLoading)
            {
                //stop the display of loading in complete method
            }
        }
    });
}
```